# Llamar usando un sim especifico

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Estaba utilizando un código para realizar llamadas usando un sim en especifico en un J7 Prime, ahora estuve intentado en un dispositivo mas actualizado, específicamente un A12.
La acción de llamar realiza sin problemas, el inconveniente ocurre que el sim no es seleccionado de forma automática, quisiera saber si es posible actualizar el código para que seleccione el sim para llamar de forma automática.

```
if (services == "Giros Tigo") {
            getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
            val sendIntent = Intent("android.intent.action.CALL")
            sendIntent.putExtra("com.android.phone.extra.slot", 0)
            sendIntent.putExtra("com.android.phone.extra", true)
            sendIntent.putExtra("simSlot", 0)
            sendIntent.data = Uri.parse("tel:*555*1*" + txtnumber.text.toString() + "*" + txtcedula.text.toString() + "*1*" + txtmonto.text.toString() + Uri.encode("#"))
            startActivityForResult(sendIntent, 1)

                startActivity(intent)
                val cd: ClipboardManager =
                    getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
                val clip = ClipData.newPlainText(
                    "AutoCopiado",
                    "*555*1*" + txtnumber.text.toString() + "*" + txtcedula.text.toString() + "*1*" + txtmonto.text.toString() + "#"
                )
                cd.setPrimaryClip(clip)
            }
```